# Installing the scala android eclipse plugin

Tags: java, android, scala

I am new to eclipse scala and android but I've been trying to build a scala android application and run it successfully for some time now. I found [this](https://github.com/banshee/AndroidProguardScala) plugin that is supposed to allow me to do that but I can't seem to make heads or tails of it.

I read the readme. I downloaded it. I copied the contents of the bin folder to the dropins folder of my eclipse instalation( which includes the sdk which includes the plugin development tools which were a requirement). I manually added the nature to the project file.

Now what?

I still can't reference scala classes from my java android app.

I guess what I am trying to ask is: How do I know when the thing is installed? 
and 
How do I work with it after adding the nature? Do i make an android project add the nature and then reference a scala project to it? 
Did I add the nature ok in the first place?

Thanks

Comment: Does it not compile at all, or is it just the auto-complete that is failing? Auto-completing Scala methods from Java is a problematic area.

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck with that some time ago, I think the trick was to create a main class in Java and immediately hand over the control to a scala class instead :)